# how to make contents flow vertically

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dynamic site where there is a parent div and children divs (they are variable in width) inside the parent one and trying to make this :
when a new div is created it is pushed downward until it the parents height is filled then start a new column and such as:

IMAGE:

[image]

```
 <style>
    .parent {
      height: 800px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .child1 {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
    }
    .child1 {
      background-color: red;
      height: 150px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child1"></div>
      <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What happens with this code?  Explain the actual issue.  And you should look into CSS grids, there are many.  Ex. Bootstrap.  They do this all for you, tested for all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS's `display: grid` is a solution for the layout described in the attached image:

```
.parent {
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    grid-auto-columns: 150px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    color: white;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.child2 {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

## The grid:

`display: grid;` to enable grid layout on the container.
`grid-gap: 2px;`specifies a gap of 2px between rows and columns in the grid.
`grid-auto-columns: 150px;` columns in the grid should be 150px wide.
`grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);` the grid will contain 4 rows of equals height.
`grid-auto-flow: column;` a new column will be created when the content reaches the bottom of the container.

## The grid elements:

Without any additional css the blue elements will each occupy a cell in the grid 1 row tall and 1 column wide.

```
.child2 {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

The red elements will span over 2 columns.

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2dx6cLr5/21/)

Comment: Grid is the best choice but also look at flex box flex-direction or even css columns if you need to fall back to older browsers as grid isn’t supported everywhere yet. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: I FORGOT ABOUT THE `GRID SPAN` WHICH MAKES SENSE NOW ... WORKS LIKE A CHARM .100K THUMBS UP